# HTML input box readonly---javascript button overrides text

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a js fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/110/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="a" readonly>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<div>
<button class="buttons">c</button>
<button class="buttons">a</button>
<button class="buttons">t</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
    });

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $('input.active').val(cntrl);
    });
});
```

The readonly attribute works when the user uses the keyboard to try and input something over the 'a' in the above example. But when the user clicks a button to insert text it seems to trump the readonly attribute and replaces the text. How can I prevent this from happening so that it is always read only.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding as to what the `readonly` attribute does. Javascript does not "obey" `readonly` unless you make it look for it. It is only intended for the ui side.

Comment: So, could you just not have the onclick event change the input? Seems like a simple fix?

Comment: thx imtheman, that was indeed what I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the buttons to change `readonly` inputs, you can change the jQuery selector to this:

```
$('input.active:not([readonly])').val(cntrl);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/YD6PL/111/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `disabled` instead of `readonly.` That works in this updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/110/. This will prevent the user from selecting the box so they won't be able to change it. Not sure if they need to be able to highlight the text in there as well, but try this first!